# LinqToSql Item has already been added. Key in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Quite randomly we're getting an error saying Item has already been added. Key in dictionary when we query a LinqToSql data context and the only way to stop it is to restart IIS.

Error message:

> > Error Message:Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Int32 Single1[System.Int32]">Int32'
> >     Key being added: 'Int32
> >     Single[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Int32])'
>
> Stack trace:
>
> > Stack Trace:   at System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2.Insert(K[] keys, V[] values, Int32& count, K key, V value)    at
> >     System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2.Preallocate(Int32 count)    at
> >     System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetGenericMethodInfo(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal
> >     genericMethod)    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(RuntimeType
> >     reflectedType, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal methodHandle)    at
> >     System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[]
> >     methodInstantiation)    at
> >     System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)    at
> >     Triton.CRM.OrganisationType.LoadOrganisationTypeInformation() in
> >     c:\Users\timg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Triton
> >     V2\TritonDataSets\Organisation\OrganisationType.cs:line 82    at
> >     Triton.CRM.OrganisationType.get_OrganisationTypeName() in
> >     c:\Users\timg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Triton
> >     V2\TritonDataSets\Organisation\OrganisationType.cs:line 31    at
> >     Triton.CRM.OrganisationType.GetAllData(Int32 PageSize, Int32
> >     Currentpage, String sortField, String sortOrder, String query, Int32
> >     personId, Int64 organisationId, String groupIdListCtv, String select,
> >     String searchValue, Boolean useFullTextSearch, List`1 groupIdList) in
> >     c:\Users\timg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Triton
> >     V2\TritonDataSets\Organisation\OrganisationType.cs:line 255    at
> >     CustomPages_GetFranchiseeSummary.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> >     at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp,
> >     Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
> >     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> >     includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I've found lots of posts mentioning it being to do with a bug in `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` but no solutions.

I also found this on Microsoft Connect but they say it was fixed in .net 4 and im running .net 4.5

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/738253

Comment: Do you have a static or Singleton DbContext?

Comment: To add context to what Mehmet is saying: that *sounds* like maybe you are incorrectly sharing a data-context between requests, which could lead to bad things like a thread-race. But more importantly, it is simply the wrong way of doing it, and can lead to gradual performance and memory degradation. A data-context is intended to be very short-lived.

Comment: No it's happening in places where a new instance of the DbContext had just been created.